# The instance of entity type 'IngredientEntity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked

Tags: c#, asp.net, typescript, api, entity-framework

I have two db tables, one for recipes and one for ingredients, but when I try to update the database it throws the exception above.

My api controller is

```
    [HttpPost("saveRecipe")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<SaveRecipeResponse>> SaveRecipe(SaveRecipeRequest request, CancellationToken requestAborted)
    {
            await _recipeRepo.UpsertAsync(_mapper.Map<RecipeEntity>(request.Recipe), requestAborted);
            foreach (var ing in request.Recipe.Ingredients)
            {
                await _ingRepo.UpsertAsync(_mapper.Map<IngredientEntity>(ing), requestAborted);            
            }
await _uow.SaveAsync();
            return new SaveRecipeResponse() { Recipe = request.Recipe, Success = true };
            // </custom:SaveRecipe>
    }
```

The client send this request:

```
save() {
    this.delegates.recipes.SaveRecipe(this.payload.recipe).subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        this.isReady = false;
        console.log(res);
      },
      error: (err) => {
        this.isReady = true;
        this.errorMsg = {message: 'save-error', details: err.message};
        console.log(err);
      },
      complete: () => {
        this.isReady = true;
        this.return();
      }
    })
  }
```

how can i insert all of the ingredients in the database? every ingredient should have a different ID so i don't know why does it throw this

Comment: Because you use generic repositories and mappers. Try searching. You create two instances of the same object.

Comment: how should i work around this? the two repositories are two different injected service

Comment: By not plastering your code with generic repositories and mappers. It is an outdated pattern resulting in problems like the one you got now. If you need help fixing your actual code, show your actual code. Create a [mre].

Comment: it's all i got, the upsertasync method is part of the library my company bought (CodeArchitects.Platform.Data) in the repository i have only a getall function wich have no problems and it extends the library where there is the upsert method. I can't see the upsert method itself just the interface

Comment: Oh but it's got "Architects" in the name so it must be good. Except it isn't. We are not their support, we can't support code we can't see. Again: the issue is caused by your code sending two instances of an object for the same PK to Entity Framework. If their code has a solution for that, you've got to ask them.

Comment: I hate it too, my company bought it, not me, it basically generates the code by itself after it gets described in a yml file... but it puts a bunch of unused imports too, makes 0 sense, i would be faster without it but whatever... i already asked them but the only answer was "yea because you are pointing at the same object"

Comment: so the problem is in the repository? if i write the code to update/insert data into database it would work with the foreach statement and all?

Comment: Look at what `_mapper.Map<RecipeEntity>(request.Recipe)` returns. It probably includes mapped ingredients, which you then pass to the repository. Then at `_mapper.Map<IngredientEntity>(ing)`, you map those ingredients _again_, and pass them to another repository. You probably just don't have to do the latter.

Comment: Thank you, now i mapped only once and it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to CodeCaster's comment, I found out data should be mapped only once. So I now save the mapped entity in a variable and then use it directly.

```
[HttpPost("saveRecipe")]
// <custom:customAttributesSaveRecipe>
    // </custom:customAttributesSaveRecipe>
public async Task<ActionResult<SaveRecipeResponse>> SaveRecipe(SaveRecipeRequest request, CancellationToken requestAborted)
{
        // <custom:SaveRecipe>
        RecipeEntity r = _mapper.Map<RecipeEntity>(request.Recipe);
        await _recipeRepo.UpsertAsync(r, requestAborted);
        foreach (var ing in r.Ingredients)
        {
            await _ingRepo.UpsertAsync(ing, requestAborted);            
        }

        await _uow.SaveAsync();

        return new SaveRecipeResponse() { Recipe = request.Recipe, Success 
= true };
        // </custom:SaveRecipe>
}
```